# Generate javafx events (KeyEvent)

Tags: java, events, javafx, keyboard, event-handling

I am trying to generate a KeyEvent by hand in javafx. My class gets data from elsewhere (say, the string "A"). This class should then take that string and convert it into a KeyEvent with the keyboard button A as the button pressed (which is then handled by my main class). I have found the function `Event.fireEvent(...)`, however I do not know what to put into it/how to construct the event itself.

Comment: You can construct a [`KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) with the appropriate parameters, depending on what you need. The target should be the node on which the event will be fired. Normally, though, you would be unlikely to want to simulate key events like this. Is there any reason you can't just process the text and pass it to some data class of some kind? What are you actually trying to do; this sounds like a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @James_D I am receiving data from an arduino controller (buttons/joystick). I have a program that relies on key events (e.g. the A button to jump) and I want to map the data from my controller into key events.

Comment: Why do you want to map them to events though? Why not just call the appropriate method you have implemented for "jump" when 'A' is pressed, instead of artificially passing it through the event handling mechanism?